# Flutter ffmpeg_kit_flutter not able to DrawText over video

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am Trying to overlay text over the Video using ffmpeg dependency.
i have tried many options, but my most recent commands are as follows,

```
await FFmpegKit.execute(
        '-i $path -vf "drawtext="fontfile=TiktokFont.ttf:text=\'Stack Overflow\':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2"" -codec:a copy  "$outputPath"')
```

**My pubspec Dependency:**

```
ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^4.5.1
```

**But the result is always like this.**

```
Error : No such filter: 'drawtext'
```

**Solutions Tried:**

- Changed the Font.tff
- Set Font in the configuration file for ffmpeg
- changed the command, removed the box
- replaced `-vf` with `-filter_complex`

> All of them give me same result as follows screenshot. [Logs]

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me How you Set Font in the configuration file for ffmpeg ?

Comment: Do you want to see the executing String code?

Comment: i am so happy you answered . you said ' Set Font in the configuration file for ffmpeg' i need this part of String code .. and if you have the full string code would be so thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg_kit_flutter` installs the `https` package by default. Try using the `full` package instead.

```
dependencies:
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full: ^4.5.1
```

You can see all the available packages [here](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit#8-packages) and detailed installation instructions [here](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter#2-installation).

Comment: ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full: ^4.5.1 it will be gives pod error on ios @Dan Harms

Comment: Feel free to ask a separate question as that sounds like a different issue than OP's.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg_kit_flutter_video` is enough for using drawtext filter. I just found it out with try and error. All available sub packages are listed [here](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit#9-packages:%7E:text=9.-,Packages,-There%20are%20eight).